# How to handle invalid XML response with utf-16 header over a utf-8 stream

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I'm getting the following error in when trying to read some XML.

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Xml.XmlException
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Private.Xml.dll: 'There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.'
```

I've identified this as the API is serving the content as utf-8 but the header is utf-16.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

I've confirmed this in tests from static files by deleting the encoding or saving the file in utf-16.  I have also confirmed that the incoming response is utf-8 looking in the response Content.Headers.ContentType.

Unfortunately I don't maintain the API and don't think that this will be getting fixed any time soon.

Is there a way to make a System.Text.XmlReader ignore the header in the stream, would be nice if there were a flag to simply ignore the doctype if they can't be bothered to make it accurate?

I think you can correct the content of XML using some kind of Schema replacement prior to final parsing?

I could always think about re-encoding the same content but it seems a little mad.

```
var mockBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>");
var mockStream = MemoryStream new(mockBytes);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Async = true;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(mockStream, settings))
{
    if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Message") & await reader.ReadAsync()) 
    {
        while (await reader.MoveToContentAsync() == XmlNodeType.Element)
        { 
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, an idea would be to open that stream with a string reader read until the first `>` char, and pass that string reader to an `XMLReader`  that way you will skip the header without reading or copying the entire stream.

Comment: `XmlReader` will ignore the encoding entirely if initialized from a `TextReader` (which supplies its own encoding) rather than directly from a `Stream`, so wrapping that with a `StreamReader` would suffice.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far

Comment: Jusdrt need to read first line with utf-16 :            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            //read one line
            sReader.ReadLine();
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

Comment: Thanks for comments re stream reader I think that will be best.  Didn't realise I could give a stream reader rather than a stream. Will do exactly that and give a bit more code for question and answer.

Comment: @jdweng: this is 1) unnecessary because `StreamReader` already ignores encoding regardless and 2) fragile because there is no rule that says XML must have newlines anywhere, so in the worst case this logic could end up skipping the entire document. If you really wanted to skip only the declaration (because it contained other incorrectness besides the encoding) you'd need a mini-parser.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : It is  necessary to skip the line with UTC-16 which XMLREADER rejects.

Comment: @jdweng: read your own code (and the OP's answer) again. If you are initializing an `XmlReader` with a `StreamReader`, then the `XmlReader` will *not* reject that line because it will ignore the encoding entirely. Merely using a `StreamReader` already solves the problem, skipping the line is no longer necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Read my comment below.  My code is more efficient.

Comment: @jdweng: that's in no way relevant to my comments, but sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments.  Using them I have been able to test that simply instantiating and passing a StreamReader is all that is required to stop the XmlReader interpreting the encoding meta in the document type definition.

```
var mockBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>");
var mockStream = MemoryStream new(mockBytes);

var sr = new StreamReader(mockStream);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Async = true;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
{
    if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Message") & await reader.ReadAsync()) 
    {
        while (await reader.MoveToContentAsync() == XmlNodeType.Element)
        { 
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is the simplest solution I can imagine other than a flag on the XmlReaderSettings that doesn't seem to exist.

Furthermore, as @Jereon says, skipping to particular characters or line endings would get very brittle and fall over if some other change happened at the API.  You would really have to try and look more carefully, perhaps pushing elements into a stack between `<?` + `?>` not easy and also fortunately not necessary.

Comment: This code reads data twice. I is more efficient to use my code in the comments above which also uses stream reader without the memory stream.

Comment: Hi @jdweng the stream is a mock element.  I'm dealing with an HTTP response really not a string, it's just for illustration.  My code is expecting a stream so arrives in the method. I only ran this back to files isolate the problem.